# Java SSLServerSocketFactory with openSSL key

Tags: java, ssl

I have an openSSL certificate and private key and want to open an SSL server socket using it.

My code so far is:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

SSLServerSocket sslSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslsocketfactory.createServerSocket(config.getTlsPort());
```

How do I add the certificate and key to this object? There seems to be no method call like this.

Comment: Some examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/SSL_client.html#wp1029618

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the key and certificate to PKCS#12 format, which you can do with an OpenSSL command or two, and then use that file as the KeyStore in PKCS#12 format.